# Where does this function converge to?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{2n}{3\cdot5\cdot7\cdots (2n+1)}$ converges to $(a)\frac{1}{4}(b)\frac{1}{2}(c)\frac{3}{4}(d)1$

I know that  $$\sum _{n=0}^\infty a_n $$ converges for $\lim _{n\to\infty}a_n =0$ . But here which should I take $a_n$. whether 
$$\frac{2n}{2n+1}$$ or $$\frac{2n}{\prod_{n=1}^\infty(2n+1)}$$ if the second one then how to solve it.

Comment: Is this an exercise based on techniques you have been taught?

Comment: And no, summands converging to zero do not necessarily give converging series.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

\begin{align*}\frac{2n}{\prod_{r=1}^{n+1}(2r-1)}=\frac{2n+1-1}{\prod_{r=1}^{n+1}(2r-1)}&=\frac1{\prod_{r=1}^n(2r-1)}-\frac1{\prod_{r=1}^{n+1}(2r-1)}
\\
\\&=T(n)-T(n-1)\end{align*}

where $T(m)=\dfrac1{\prod_{r=1}^{m+1}(2r-1)}$

**See also**: [Telescoping series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series)

Comment: @AndréNicolas, Thanks for your observation